# disable radio button initially javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set the radio button to disable initially with javascript, Here is my code.
HTML:

```js
document.getElementById("authorise1_radio").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("authorise2_radio").disabled = true;
```

```html
<input checked class="radio_input" id="authorise1_radio" name="authorise1_radio" type="radio" value="authorise">
<label class="radio_label" for="authorise1_radio">Yes</label>

<input class="radio_input" id="authorise2_radio" name="authorise2_radio" type="radio" value="authorise">
<label class="radio_label" for="authorise2_radio">No</label>
```

I tried the same code in w3school.com and it works fine.
This is the code there:

```js
    document.getElementById("myRadio").disabled = true;
```

```html
Radio Button:
<input type="radio" id="myRadio">
```

Comment: Works [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/fcns49Lq/), add your complete code

Comment: Maybe you you put in window.onload = function disableRadioButton()

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:** you can use javascript code below of html code of radio button. like following: (then it may works)

```
<input checked class="radio_input" id="authorise1_radio" name="authorise_radio" type="radio" value="authorise">
<label class="radio_label" for="authorise1_radio">Yes</label>

<input class="radio_input" id="authorise2_radio" name="authorise_radio" type="radio" value="authorise">
<label class="radio_label" for="authorise2_radio">No</label>
<script>
document.getElementById("authorise1_radio").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("authorise2_radio").disabled = true;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the script between the `<head>` tags in your html

```
<head>
<script>
    document.getElementById("radioButton").disabled = true;
 </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there's nothing wrong with your code.

try using

```
document.getElementById("myRadio").readonly = true;
```

I guess that would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

**Onclick change State**

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var checked = 0;
function change() {
    if (checked === 0) {
        checked++;
    }else {
        document.getElementById("myRadioID").checked = false;
        checked = 0;
    }
}
</script>
Radio Button:
<input type="radio" id="myRadioID" onclick="javascript:change();"/>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

> Please put this below code in footer section

```
<script>
     document.getElementById("authorise1_radio").disabled = true;
</script>
```